# Java - Writing a FilterInputStream

Tags: java, multithreading, inputstream

I want to write an InputStream that gets its input from another InputStream and does something to it. I found out that a FilterInputStream provides exactly what i was looking for.

So what's best practice when writing my own FilterInputStream? The standard implementation just passes all read requests to the original InputStream. So I would have something like this:

```
public class MyFilterInputStream extends FilterInputStream {

  public MyFilterInputStream(InputStream inputStream) {
    super(inputStream);
  }

  public int read() {
    int i = in.read();
    int j = doSomething(i);
    return j;
  }
  ...
}
```

Would it be better to use a multithreaded approach where, e.g., a thread constantly reads from **in** and stores the data in a buffer that then is accessed by MyFilterInputStream.read()? (Especially when the amount of data that is produced differs from the amount that is consumed)

Update:

The concrete application would be a raw audio stream as input and a (somehow) compressed audio stream as output.

Comment: What do you exactly want to do?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that your solution needs another Thread. The idea you described would lead to something like a BufferedFilterInputStream which is perfect legal, but is a differente thing than you said you wanted.

A Filter is like a Proxy, it goes between two things to provide some extra functionallity in a transparet way, so first thing is to decide what is the thing you want to provide :)

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to implement it using Decorator pattern. Please have a look at http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2004/jw-0412-decorator.html